# Error when importing txt file of numbers into python list

Tags: python, list, import, binary, utf

Basically, I have a txt file which is full of numbers 1-5000, in no order. I am trying to import them into a python script to manipulate them and find info on averages, and whatnot.

I've tried many different methods of importing the list, but it always errors with "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte"

```
list = []

with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for x in content:
        row = x.split()
        list.append(int(row[0]))

print(list)
```

The expected result is a list of numbers, in int format

However, I either get that error or in certain executions, I get a list filled with `\x00` between every character.

Comment: What does your number.txt look like? I tried your code on a file where the numbers are separated by new line and it worked perfectly for me [numbers.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aCsq.png) [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AY8F.png)

Comment: Can u post a small sample of your number file. It looks like you have hex codes scattered in your data file in between the numbers. One way however would be to replace all the hex codes with spaces or whatever suits your requirement to split data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try UTF-16 to encode and then split as per your code.

my code is below.

```
with open(path_to_file,'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()
contents = contents.rstrip("\n").decode("utf-16")
```

Hope it helps.

**MV**

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried that but it hadnt worked previously. It worked with your method, I think there was something wrong with my text file!

Comment: Glad to know it helped.